# Non correlated subquery to determine customer Records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, correlated-subquery

I have two tables, customer and customer_order

**customer**

```
cust_id, cust_name
121 Acme Wholesalers
234 Griffen Electric
336 East Coast Marine Supplies
544 Sanford Automotive
```

**customer_orders**

```
order_num,cust_id,order_date
1 121 2019-01-15
2 234 2019-07-24
3 336 2020-05-02
4 121 2019-01-15
5 336 2020-03-19
6 234 2019-07-24
7 121 2019-01-15
8 336 2020-06-12
```

I need to find out the name of each customer who has placed exactly 3 orders but using a non-correlated subquery and without JOINS

I have got the same query results using correlated query

```
    SELECT c.cust_name FROM customer c WHERE cust_id 
    IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cust_id) FROM customer_order )
```

but this time I need same results using non-correlated and without join also

Comment: *using a non-correlated subquery and without JOINS* - why? Are you sure you should be using a *relational* database?

Comment: your query is not a valid mysql query ..  so try explain better .. IN ( select group_concat(..) seems wrong to me..  which db you are really using ???

Comment: I can achieve this task using join but this time I need using non- correlated so that my concept will be clear

Comment: You tried IN which is a correct direction. Just select `cust_id`s with a proper count.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the big rock is finding cust_id values that have exactly three occurrences in customer_order we can do something like this

```
SELECT o.cust_id 
  FROM customer_orders o
 GROUP
    BY o.cust_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

referencing the aggregate in a HAVING clause to restrict rows are returned.

we could use this query as an inline view (or, derived table, in the the mysql parlance), and then

```
SELECT n.cust_id
  FROM ( 
         -- cust_id that have exactly three rows
         SELECT o.cust_id 
           FROM customer_orders o
          GROUP
             BY o.cust_id
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
       ) n
```

and typically do a JOIN to the customers table to retrieve the name.

given a weird restriction of "no joins",  we could (less optimally) use an   `WHERE foo IN (subquery)` form

Comment: Thanks @spencer got the result